# How to get a array variable value?

Tags: php, arrays, function

```
$lang['profil_basic_medeni'] = array( 
    1 => 'Bekâr',
    2 => 'Evli',
    3 => 'Nişanlı',
    4 => 'İlişkide',
    5 => 'Ayrılmış',
    6 => 'Boşanmış'
    );
 $lang['profil_basic_sac'] = array( 
    1 => 'Normal',
    2 => 'Kısa',
    3 => 'Orta',
    4 => 'Uzun',
    5 => 'Fönlü',
    6 => 'Saçsız (Dazlak)',
    7 => 'Karışık/Dağınık',
    8 => 'Her Zaman Bol Jöleli :)'
    );

function sGetVAL($item,$valno) {
  $sonuc = $lang[$item][$valno];
  return $sonuc;
} 

$tempVAL1 = sGetVAL('profil_basic_medeni','3'); // return null
//or
$tempVAL2 = sGetVAL('profil_basic_sac','7'); // return null
```

`$tempVAL1` or `$tempVAL2` always return `null`. why ? how to fix function sGetVAL ???

Comment: Why do you need the function anyway? You could directly access the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using literal indexes like numeric indexes?
Because the array `$lang` is not visible in function?

try this:

```
$tempVAL1 = sGetVAL('profil_basic_medeni',3); // return null
//or
$tempVAL2 = sGetVAL('profil_basic_sac',7); // return null
```

and this:

```
function sGetVAL($item,$valno) {
   global $lang;
   $sonuc = $lang[$item][$valno];
   return $sonuc;
}
```

Comment: You can interchange numeric *string* indexes with numerical ones. There is no difference. `$a['1'] == $a[1]`

Comment: He could also pass the array in to the function ... globals are evil :p

Comment: yup, both comments are right.  
But this is the way of smallest pain for him, probably :)

Comment: @Erik: Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: 3 other similar answers posted first, I  didn't think my version taking the array as a param was a significant enough of an improvment to leave up.

Comment: @Marek Sebera: Well, the answer should still be correct. Your first remark is *not* the reason for the error.

Comment: @Felix King: I'm for using the same variable type for setting and retrieving index key. Right, it isn't reason for error, but it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

your array is global, but your function uses a local version of it (which is different and uninitialized).

either write `global $lang` first in your function, or use `$GLOBALS['lang']` to access the array.

Answer (score 1):

`$lang` is a global variable, that is not visible to `sGetVal`. Functions can usually only see variables that they define themselves (and Superglobals like `$_POST` and `$_GET`).

You could use

```
function sGetVAL($item,$valno) {
  global $lang;
  $sonuc = $lang[$item][$valno];
  return $sonuc;
}
```

but it would be better to do without global variables altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The `sGetVal` function can't see the array `$lang` as you haven't used the `global` keyword to bring it into scope. Read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).